# Plot in pandas load in separate window after run

Tags: python, pandas, boxplot

How to load pandas plot in separate window? It appears very small in Jupyter notebook and don't appears at all in Pycharm.

Here is my code for plotting:

```
data.reset_index().boxplot('Col', by='Row')
```

Comment: You can pass in `figsize` to make the plot bigger. 
`data.reset_index().boxplot('Col', by='Row', figsize=(15,15))`